# I need to parse some text and integers from a file

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with a problem I'm trying to do. My goal is to import a file that contains football teams names, and then the number of wins and losses, and then if a team's average is greater than .500, than I have to write that teams name, and average to a new file. And then I have to write the teams under .500 to a seperate file. so far I have my code so that it reads eachline of the file, but I can't figure out how to analyize each line of code. I'm really just looking for any advice I could get at this point, and it would be greatly appreciated.

```
scores = open("fbscores.txt",'r')
eachline = scores.readline()
while eachline != "":
    print(eachline)
    eachline = scores.readline()
scores.close()
```

Comment: The best way to get help is to post a some lines of the file you want to parse

Comment: How are the lines in the file delimited, by space? comma? something else? You might want to look at the split method of strings. Also, when reading/writing files, best practice is to wrap them in the "with" keyword [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html). Personally, I would also use a for loop to iterate through the lines "for line in scores.readlines():".

Comment: It looks like you have a good bit of coding work ahead of you. My advice is to get started.

Comment: the file is formatted like this: NYGiants     5        2, its just seperated by a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an example line of the file like this:

```
Cowboys 4 1
```

Then some code might look like this:

```
line = scores.readline().split()
teamName = line[0]
wins = int(line[1])
losses = int(line[2])

if wins > losses:
    print(teamName + "'s record is over .500!")
    goodTeams.write(line)
    goodTeams.write() #make a new line
else:
    print(teamName + "'s record is <= .500.")
    badTeams.write(line)
    badTeams.write()
```

To find the average of a team with x wins and y losses, do:

```
"%0.3f" % (x/(x+y))
```

Gives:

```
>>> "%0.3f" % (4/(4+1))
'0.800'
>>>
```

Comment: If you find an answer helpful, please provide feedback in the form of an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely going to end up using the split method, which breaks a string apart into a list element each time it encounters a certain character.  Read more here http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I have that website as a bookmark haha

Answer (score 0):

You could use a high level library to do so, like [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).

It has many of the functionnalities you want!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really helpful if you post some lines from your input. 
According to your description, I assuming each line in your input has the following layout:

```
[NAME] X Y
```

Where, `NAME` is the team name, `X` is the number of wins, `Y`, the number of loses.
You can simply split the line by any delimiter (which is 'space' in this example case),

```
eachline = eachline.split()
```

If there was a comma separator, then you do `eachline = eachline.split(',')` and so on, you get the idea.

Then eachline will store a list of the following structure `['NAME', X, Y]`
Then you can access `X` and `Y` to average them using: `eachline[0]` and `eachline[1]` respectively.